# What is the type of my batteries?

Tags: batteries, inverter

I have an inverter that requires to set the batteries type.
The inverter accept 3 kind of batteries : AGM , GEL , FLD.
But i can't find any information on my batteries about these types.
The only thing i can read on my batteries is **Calcium Premium**.
What type should i select on my inverter ?

Thank you !

**Update**
Battery is :

**Solite Calcium Premium 68022**

[image]

[image]

Comment: AGM = absorbed glass mat. GEL = gelled electrolyte. FLD = flooded. Can you post a picture of the top of your battery? If it has removable caps on top for checking or adding water, it is a flooded type battery.

Comment: I've updated my question with some battery details

Answer (score 3):

Calcium Premium refers to the chemistry of the electrodes in the battery. Rather than pure lead they will use a lead-calcium alloy to produce a battery which has lower self discharge over time. It is most likely to be an AGM battery.

Do you have information on the brand/model number of the battery? Without knowing this you won't be able to tell the type of electrolyte format (ie AGM, GEL,...). You might be able to determine this by physical inspection of the battery. Does it slosh when you move it from side to side? If so it is FLD (flooded or wet cell). Are there any vents or ports on the battery? AGM and GEL are hard to tell apart by inspection.

Additionally, you need to ensure that the inverter is supplying current at a reasonable level for the battery. You don't want to charge it too hard as this can damage the battery, but charging too slowly will take a very long time.

Assuming this is a vehicle battery (or similar medium size lead acid cell) then you'd be looking at an 8-10 hour charge time from dead flat to full. Take the capacity in Ah, divide by Amps supplied by your charger and that will give you the hours to charge from empty to full. The key thing with both AGM and GEL cell batteries is to prevent over charging. If your charger has an automatic cutoff then this should be fine, otherwise you will have to monitor closely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated my question with some battery details

Comment: Ok, a bit of Google translation later, I think I've found your battery: http://www.batteryplus.gr/ell/mobile/product/%CE%9C%CE%A0%CE%91%CE%A4%CE%91%CE%A1%CE%99%CE%91-SOLITE-68022-AH-20hr-180-AEN-1050

Comment: ok , but what is the type ?

Comment: If this matches your battery (the fill level markings would be a dead giveaway, then you have a FLD = flooded or wet cell type battery.

Comment: Actually the image does not match. But the specifications are the same. Please look at my updated question , because i've added a new image. In the upper part of the battery , there are only the cable connectors , and nothing else.

Comment: The image might be generic. Solite seem to specialise in "maintenance free" batteries, by which they mean flooded cells that don't require topping up.

Comment: So as a last word , you think i should choose FLD on my inverter ?

Comment: I believe it is a flooded battery, also, but of course nobody can make the final decision except you. One piece of information that might help is that AGM and GEL type batteries are generally more expensive than similar size FLD batteries. So if the battery was a good value, that is another indication that it is type FLD. Here in the US, at least, AGM and GEL batteries usually advertise that they are that type, because it helps to justify the higher price. The lack of advertising also suggests type FLD.

Comment: The problem is that the battery manufacturer has a poor support and doesn't respond to emails or phone calls. The cost of these batteries was around 160 USD ( each of them ). But the words "Calcium Premium" does not mean anything ? I mean both type AGM , GEL , FLD can use lead-Calcium or ?????

Comment: I am not really an expert. But I believe many different types of lead batteries contain calcium. Based on price, I am pretty sure it is not an AGM or GEL battery.

Comment: Sorry , this is a link with full battery specifications : http://www.solitebatteries.com/images/brochure.pdf. Search for 68021 . As you can see , on one of columns there's a parameter Acid volume. So may be a help to determine the type ?

Comment: @ferdi it's definitely an FLD based on the spec sheet.